# karma start throwing useragent error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, yeoman, karma-runner

I generated an app using yeoman by doing this in a folder called sw-front:

```
yo angular
```

I installed karma like this

```
npm install -g karma
npm install -g karma-cli
```

grunt serve works fine.

**karma -v** throws the same error:
mm-mac-2186:sw-front pkatepalli$ **karma start**

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'useragent'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pkatepalli/Desktop/hands-on-angular/sw-front/node_modules/karma/lib/helper.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

**module.js:**

```
var Module = function() {
  var providers = [];

  this.factory = function(name, factory) {
    providers.push([name, 'factory', factory]);
    return this;
  };

  this.value = function(name, value) {
    providers.push([name, 'value', value]);
    return this;
  };

  this.type = function(name, type) {
    providers.push([name, 'type', type]);
    return this;
  };

  this.forEach = function(iterator) {
    providers.forEach(iterator);
  };
};

module.exports = Module;
```

mm-mac-2186:sw-front pkatepalli$ node -v

```
v0.10.28
```

mm-mac-2186:sw-front pkatepalli$ npm -v

```
1.4.9
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` (without any further arguments)?

Comment: yeah I ran that and bower install

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm cache clean
```

And removing the node_modules directory, if it exists, where you are running the commands form.

Then rebuild/reinstall